# jQuery not selecting right option at form with dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

I have a form on a modal with the following HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col m2 s12">
  <select id="user_id" name="user_id">
    <option value="1">John</option>
    <option value="2">Jane</option>
    <option value="3">Joe</option>
  </select>
  <label for="user_id">User</label>
</div>
```

I want the right item to be selected when I click on an event with the following jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  themeSystem: 'jquery-ui',
  slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm",
  timeFormat: 'h:mm',
  businessHours: {
    start: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
    end: '19:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
  },
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
  },
  buttonText: {
    today: 'Vandaag',
    month: 'Maand',
    week: 'Week',
    day: 'Dag',
    list: 'Lijst'
  },
  defaultView: 'month',
  weekNumbers: false,
  weekends: false,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: 'urltoEvents',

  eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var eventId = calEvent.id;
    var userId = calEvent.user_id;
    var comment = calEvent.comment;
    var startTime = calEvent.start_time;
    var startDate = calEvent.start_date;
    var endTime = calEvent.end_time;
    var endDate = calEvent.end_date;


    $("#updateEvent #start_time").val(startTime);
    $("#updateEvent #start_date").val(startDate);
    $("#updateEvent #end_time").val(endTime);
    $("#updateEvent #end_date").val(endDate);
    $("#updateEvent #user_id").val(userId).attr("selected", "selected");
    $("#updateEvent #eventId").val(eventId);
    $("#updateEvent #comment").val(comment);
    $('#updateEvent').modal('open');
  }
});
```

Unfortunately this is not working and it's showing the first option as the selected one. Can somebody help me with this please? Thanks.

Comment: "the right item to be selected when [you] click on an event" - the dropdown selects the correct name on dropdown - what "event" are you referring to? Can you make a fiddle ? (a listener perhaps may help?)

Comment: Not sure how to make a fiddle, because the click event it's from fullCalendar.

Comment: can you specify the event at least? The jsfiddle only needs to reflect a minimal example to replicate the problem

Comment: The event is this within the fullCalendar: eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                        var userId = calEvent.user_id;
                     $("#updateEvent #user_id").val(userId).attr("selected","selected");
}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0jo5ahbL/8/ this is actually working, so the problem should be somewhere at the eventClick from fullcalendar?

Comment: add a click event listener to calEvent, that would be my guess.. it's trickier without  seeing the actual/full  code.

Comment: Give this a try.....I modified your code to use the examples listed in my answer below.  https://jsfiddle.net/0jo5ahbL/13/

Comment: Thanks, but not sure how to use this for my code. It's the other way around right? When I click something, the dropdown (in a form on a modal) should select the matching value from the 'userId'.

Comment: No, for you to retrieve the selected options and get either the value or the text you leave the .val() or .text() empty.   empty will perform the GET and adding a value such as .val("something here") or .text("something here") will trigger the SET

Comment: Really trying to understand this, but I am not getting this. I am sorry...

Answer (score 2):

Try next solution, since i don't know what is "#updateElement" i will ignore it.

```
var userId = calEvent.user_id;
$("#user_id").val(userId).change();
```

Also, the variable **userId** should hold values of type string, for example: "1", "2" or "3".

Comment: #updateElement is for selecting the main form id. I have tried this option with change(), but it's not working for me.

Comment: Please, check the developer console too, maybe there is an error and the code is not working. Also, try a basic test too, for example: `$("#user_id").val("3").change();`

Comment: I am trying this, but no change also. When I console log the 'userId' it's working though.

Comment: Ok, lets remove all code associated to the "**calendar**". Try next basic example in replacement of you  $(document).ready(...). Define this one like:  `$(document).ready(function() {$("#user_id").val("2").change(); $('#updateEvent').modal('open');});` Just tellme if this works fine, it should change the select input to second value and opens the modal.

Comment: It's actually not working. Maybe I should take a closer look at the HTML?

Comment: And if you first opens the modal, like this: `$(document).ready(function() {$('#updateEvent').modal('open'); setTimeout(function(){$("#user_id").val("2").change();}, 5000); });` This should first opens the modal and 5 seconds later make the change on the select. At least tellme if the modals opens or not...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180593/discussion-between-erik180486-and-d-smania).

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to set the user id for the selected box and assuming, for example, that the user id is #2 is in the value of the options list then all you need to do is this.

```
  $("#user_id").val("2");
```

However, your title suggests that you are not trying to set the value of the selected option but rather to read the selected value.

```
$("#user_id").on("change", function() {
   console.log("User ID: " +  $("#user_id option:selected").val());
   console.log("User Name: " +  $("#user_id option:selected").text());
});
```

Comment: No effect for me. It's not console logging anything for me.

Comment: My goal is to show the name from the select options of the corresponding value from the 'userId' in jQuery

Comment: OK, if you are wanting to show the name Jane for userid #2 then this is what you need.  ($("#user_id option:selected").text();

Comment: I need to tell the value somewhere right? When I am trying this:                     ($("#updateEvent #user_id option:selected").val(userId).text()); it's also not working.

Comment: if you are trying to set the value then you add a parameter, if you are trying to read a value then you leave it empty.  In addition, the form id is overkill.   As an ID name can only exist once in the DOM, unlike a class that can be repeated many times.

Comment: I have set the value with var userId = calEvent.user_id; but now I want to show the name which matched the is from userId in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot the answer was quiet simple. I am not sure if it's because I am using 'Materialize', but I had to add 'formSelect()' to the code, so this was working for me:

```
$("#user_id").val(userId).change();
$("#user_id").formSelect();
```